# Join multiple brush strokes into shape I can fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, adobe-draw

In illustrator if I use the brush tool and draw one complete enclosed shape I can then add a fill colour and changing the stroke color changes the color of the lines i drew. However if I draw a shape using the brush tool in parts (e.g letting go of the mouse then drawing again) even if it is fully enclosed I cannot apply a fill in the same way. If I use object->expand then it converts the lines themselves into the objects that the fill color gets applied too.

How can I draw a shape using the brush tool in multiple strokes and then convert it to the outline of a path so I can apply a fill and change the stroke?

Here's a picture of how it's currently working. I've used different colour brushes here just to show where one brush stroke begins and ends but normally the brush strokes would all be one color. I'm importing from adobe draw hence why I'm working with brush strokes

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use the Selection Tool (black arrow tool) or the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) and click-drag around the works
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the 4 open path sections into one:

[image: Joinery]